# Xcode coding help NSButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, if-statement, nsbutton

I am a new Mac progremmer and
I am trying to do some theng like: with Obj-c

```
... == Something that I know how to do

...

...

wait (for user)

button clickd (some button)

if button 1 clickd {

...

wait (for user)

button clickd (some button)

if dutton 1 clickd {

...
 } 

else if dutton 2 clickd {
... 
}
}

else if button 2 clickd {

...
 }

else {

...
 }
```

Comment: please learn how to properly format your post!

Comment: yes you may want to reformat that so it is better readable.

Answer (score 0):

Move your else if block to separate methods and use `setAction:` to connect a button and its action method . You can also use Interface builder to connect methods to buttons.